# Sending UTM parameters in virtual pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, utm

Is there a way to track UTM parameters with a virtual pageview? When we fire a virtual pageview, the documentation doesn't show UTM and when I manually define it as part of the URL, it gets lost. Am I missing something?

This is the code snippet:

```
dataLayer.push({
      'event':'VirtualPageview',
      'virtualPageURL': '/url-collateral-playbook-thank-you-2/',                  
});
window.location='https://lp.URL.com/rs/804-TEY-921/images/url%20-%url%url%url%20%28new%29.pdf';
```

Comment: I can't see the param in your code?!

Comment: Let's say the page URL is the following. The UTM parameter doesn't "catch" /url-collateral-playbook-thank-you-2?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium&utm_campaign=campaign

Comment: What do you think about "setting session storage" as a solution? (i.e. https://www.brightforestmedia.com/set-sessionstorage-of-utm-in-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Hey mate! Did you figure it out?